# Odd Date/Time format

Tags: powershell, datetime, registry

I have a single program in the Uninstalls registry key with an odd date/time. The value reported is '1533407816', but the actual date is most likely '20180804', which is what all the other Autodesk products installed that day report as.
I am using `[datetime]::ParseExact($program.GetValue('InstallDate'),'yyyyMMdd',$null)` to convert those dates to a proper DateTime, but not sure what mechanism I need for the odd one. Or if it's even meaningful data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value is likely a [*Unix time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) stamp, which is the number of *seconds* that have elapsed since midnight (UTC) of 1 Jan 1970.

You can convert this value to a `[datetime]` instance in *local* time as follows:

```
[DateTimeOffset]::FromUnixTimeSeconds(1533407816).LocalDateTime
```

To get a UTC `[datetime]` instance instead, use `.UtcDateTime`.

Alternatively, work directly with the [`[System.DateTimeOffset]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset) instance returned by [`[DateTimeOffset]::FromUnixTimeSeconds()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds).

Note:

- Unix time stamps are signed 32-bit integers (`[int]`) in *seconds*.
  As an aside, this means that the latest date that they can represent is in the year `2038`, a limitation known as the [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).
- By contrast, `[datetime]` instances have a resolution of *100 nanoseconds*, called *ticks*, stored in the `.Ticks` property, whose type is `[long]` (`[System.Int64]` a signed 64-bit integer). To manually convert seconds to ticks, multiply them with `10000000L` (`1e7L`).

**Simple helper function**:

```
function convertFrom-UnixTime {
  param([int] $Value)
  [DateTimeOffset]::FromUnixTimeSeconds($Value).LocalDateTime
}
```

In action, in the [Eastern Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone), using the `en-US` culture:

```
PS> convertFrom-UnixTime 1533407816

Saturday, August 4, 2018 2:36:56 PM
```

Expressed in [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (`en-US` culture):

```
PS> (convertFrom-UnixTime 1533407816).ToUniversalTime()

Saturday, August 4, 2018 6:36:56 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

That odd value to me looks like a Unix Timestamp.

Here's a function that will convert it to a normal date

```
function ConvertFrom-UnixTimeStamp([Int64]$unixTimeStamp, [switch]$asUtc) {
    if ($unixTimeStamp -gt 253402430399) {
        Write-Error "Cannot convert $unixTimeStamp to DateTime. Only integer values up to 253402430399 are valid."
    }
    elseif ($unixTimeStamp -gt [Int32]::MaxValue) {
        Write-Warning "The given value exceeds the [Int32]::MaxValue and therefore enters the Year2038 Unix bug.."
    }
    [DateTime]$origin = New-Object System.DateTime 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, Utc

    if ($asUtc) { return $origin.AddSeconds($unixTimeStamp) }
    return ($origin.AddSeconds($unixTimeStamp)).ToLocalTime()
}
```

`ConvertFrom-UnixTimeStamp 1533407816 -asUtc` will yield a DateTime object:

> Saturday, August 4, 2018 18:36:56